Visual Studio Code custom language
I am working on a project (and I don't know if this is possible) that could have a custom language using a VS Code extension. This easy language will translate to matching file in go code
For example:
Call sub-rule: "DateTimeConvert" (LocalDateTime: dateTimeVariable, Use24HourClock: false) save response in: newDateTime

func DateTimeConvert(localDateTime time.Time, use24HourClock bool) time.Time {
    // code to convert here
}

Then in a separate file it would create a go function

Are you asking how to write a VSCode extension for a custom language? There are docs for that, like Language Extensions Overview (not that I've ever done it myself).

Sort of.. yes it will be a custom language like a wizard.. so those writing the rules do not have to know Golang. But when they create a statement, this will translate into a Golang function in another file that they don't need to see

So then you're asking two things: 1) How to write a transpiled language, 2) How to write a VSCode extension that handles it. Is that right?

yes on both accounts. I just to know if it's possible. If so, then I can plan the requirements of the software around this functionality

Actually.. I am thinking it is possible.. I just forgot about Typescript/JS!
